# Hadoop on windows: Getting exception "not a valid DFS filename"

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm new to hadoop & struggling in initial stage.
 In eclipse I have written word count program and created the JAR for wordcount program.

I'm trying to run it using below hadoop command:

```
$ ./hadoop jar C:/cygwin64/home/PAKU/hadoop-1.2.1/wordcount.jar com.hadoopexpert.WordCountDriver file:///C:/cygwin64/home/PAKU/work/hadoopdata/tmp/dfs/ddata/file.txt file:///C:/cygwin64/home/PAKU/hadoop-dir/datadir/tmp/output
```

And I'm  getting the exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /C:/cygwin64/home/PAKU/work/hadoopdata/tmp/mapred/staging/PAKU/.staging from hdfs://localhost:50000/C:/cygwin64/home/PAKU/work/hadoopdata/tmp/mapred/staging/PAKU/.staging is not a valid DFS filename.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:788)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
        at com.hadoopexpert.WordCountDriver.main(WordCountDriver.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Note: I'm running hadoop on windows using cygwin.

Code:

```
public class WordCountDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Job job = new Job();
            job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            job.setJarByClass(WordCountDriver.class);

            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
            try {
                System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 :-1);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context){
        int total = 0;
        while(value.iterator().hasNext()){
            IntWritable i = value.iterator().next();
            int i1= i.get();
            total += i1;
        }
        try {
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(total));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context){
        String s = value.toString();
        for(String word :s.split(" ")){
            Text text = new Text(word);
            IntWritable intW = new IntWritable(1);
            try {
                context.write(text, intW);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Can anybody help me to run my first hadoop program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put up the code. I think you have specified an invalid path in your `main`.

Comment: @AniMenon --I have added code. Can you please help

Comment: @AniMenon --How to get the HDFS location through command line?

Answer (score 2):

You have specified local paths for `FileInputFormat` and `FileOutputFormat`.

Put the file in hdfs and then use the hdfs paths.

---

Steps:

1. First `put`(or `copyFromLocal`) the file to hdfs:

   ```
   hdfs dfs -put /local/file/locaion hdfs://ip_add:port/hdfs_location
   ```
2. You may check the file using `ls`:

   ```
   hdfs dfs -ls /hdfs_location/
   ```

Now give the hdfs location as your argument for input and give a new directory for the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not uploaded your file in hdfs. You can do that by using put command of hadoop. Once the file will be in hdfs directory then I think it should work